# Asynchronous loading of images results in glitch on launch

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

When opening my app, a table view is the first thing that appears. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I'm using GCD to asynchronously load images into the table view (they are not fetched from the web, but are stored locally in a model). Although this works, there is a short 'glitch' when the table view shows up for the first time. As you can guess, this is because the images are loaded a split second after the table view has appeared on screen.

I would like to get rid of this, so I was wondering if there was a way to test whether the images have been loaded before presenting the table view.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Clarification:** I'm using GCD in order to have butter-smooth scrolling. This works great, so I would like to keep everything pretty much exactly the way it is. I would just like to get rid of the glitch on launch.

Comment: You can use a NSDictionary as a image cache, use index as key and UIImage as value. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, first check if there is a UIImage at indexPath, if not, load it then insert it in cache.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps load the images, then display the view?

Comment: My question is how to do that. How do I asynchronously load images in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, and then delay the presentation of the table view until they have been loaded? Remember, this should only happen on launch and not when scrolling. Otherwise, this would defeat the purpose of having it done asynchronously.